# Eclipse error while compiling and running Android app

Tags: android, eclipse, compiler-construction

I have a multi library android project, there is a problem: Most of times I should run app more than one time to have changes to my libraries applied in main project. Seems compiler doesn't sense changes to my codes in first compile. And after second or third run it prompts this in console:

```
Dx 
trouble writing output: already prepared
```

Then it applies all changes!

It can be fixed by Clean & Rebuild, but happens again.

Comment: Clean & Rebuild Projects?

Comment: @Zhuinden Yes it works, but I can't clean and rebuild a hundred times per day :)

Answer (score 0):

May be a issue due to sdk version in use..

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61710